# How to manually add data in Gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have done this thing and it displays an error as `Index was out of range. Must be negative and non zero value.` In the following code,

```
Dim index_flag as Integer = 0
GridView1.Rows(index_flag).Cells(1).Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(index_flag).Item("curr_datetime").ToString
GridView1.Rows(index_flag).Cells(2).Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(index_flag).Item("site_id").ToString
GridView1.Rows(index_flag).Cells(2).Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(index_flag).Item("site_name").ToString
GridView1.Rows(index_flag).Cells(3).Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(index_flag).Item("dc_volt").ToString
```

Comment: I think  `GridView1.Rows(index_flag).Cells(0)` is missed...

Comment: you have to check for `If ds.Tables.Count > 0 AndAlso ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then`

Comment: @ Sac Why? Please explain it briefly?

Comment: It is just a safe side. so if there is no table or row available then it will not go to find `ds.Tables(0)` or  `ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)` ...

Comment: @Sac go to this link. There is the main problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16312953/load-grid-data-from-data-base-to-gridview-without-using-binding-method

Answer (score 8):

I think you should use datatable.
Prepare your datatable as per your need and bind this datatable to your grid view 
here is the example of C# but you can do same thing with syntax of VB.NET

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("sr_no");
        dt.Columns.Add("item_name");
        dt.Columns.Add("item_id");
        dt.Columns.Add("qty");
        dt.Columns.Add("rate");
        dt.Columns.Add("total");

        var dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["sr_no"] = txtSr.Text;
        dr["item_name"] = ddlItem.SelectedItem.Text;
        dr["item_id"] = ddlItem.SelectedValue;
        dr["qty"] = txtQty.Text;
        dr["rate"] = txtRate.Text;
        dr["total"] = int.Parse(txtQty.Text) * int.Parse(txtRate.Text);

        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
```

Comment: You should also `GridView1.DataSource = dt;`

Answer (score 3):

Please try this, how it will help you.

```
DataTable dt;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        dt = new DataTable();
        MakeDataTable();
    }
    else
    {
        dt = (DataTable)ViewState["DataTable"];
    }
    ViewState["DataTable"] = dt;
}

private void MakeDataTable()
{
    dt.Columns.Add("Name");
    dt.Columns.Add("Number");
}

protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AddToDataTable();
    BindGrid();
}

private void AddToDataTable()
{
    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["Name"] = txtName.Text;
    dr["Number"] = txtNumber.Text;
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}

private void BindGrid()
{
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By Manually add values from textbox to gridview the following method is easy. try this

code

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataColumn dc = new DataColumn();

        if (dt.Columns.Count == 0)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add("Title1", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Title2", typeof(string));
        }

        DataRow NewRow = dt.NewRow();
        NewRow[0] = TextBox1.Text;
        NewRow[1] = TextBox2.Text;
        dt.Rows.Add(NewRow);
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to add each and every row from the datatable to the GridView? As much as possible please use GridView.DataSource = DataTable and GridView. DataBind(). Which will do the job of adding the data from the data table to the grid view.

Comment: please check my full code there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16312953/load-grid-data-from-data-base-to-gridview-without-using-binding-method

Comment: and i need to add value in each and every cells because some cells are dependent on some cells values

Comment: If you have to add it this way then please check @Mandeep Singh's answer. Though I would still advice you not to do it this way. There would always be a way to render the cells contents depending on some condition in a better way. Cheeers!

Comment: @mandeep singh answer is wrong bcz that add property is not for gridview. as it is for datagridview

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the GridView1.Rows.Add()

```
Dim index_flag as Integer = 0
GridView.Rows.Add()
        GridView1.Rows(index_flag).Cells(1).Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(index_flag).Item("curr_datetime").ToString

        GridView1.Rows(index_flag).Cells(2).Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(index_flag).Item("site_id").ToString
        GridView1.Rows(index_flag).Cells(2).Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(index_flag).Item("site_name").ToString
        GridView1.Rows(index_flag).Cells(3).Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(index_flag).Item("dc_volt").ToString
```

`UPDATE`

For Asp GridView check this link
I have reviewed your question, you can check on this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/467788/Dynamically-adding-and-deleting-rows-from-ASP-NET

Comment: I have reviewed your question, you can check on this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/467788/Dynamically-adding-and-deleting-rows-from-ASP-NET